# What is the "<real>" tag in a plist?

Tags: plist

I'm trying to figure out what the  tag is in a plist. I have provided a image taken from the LocationPermissions.plist . I know that the  has to do with time but im not sure how. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dECxb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists.html), `<real>` if for floating-point numbers. There seems no official documentation for that specific file, but, if you enter

> 514567909.6906989

in the [Apple Cocoa Core Data timestamp converter](https://www.epochconverter.com/coredata), you get:

> Sat, 22 Apr 2017 15:31:49 GMT

Please note that I'm no apple or safari expert and do not have direct access to such a file. Your screentshot does not contain very much info either, at least this explanation sounds reasonable.